# Connections between groups in a hive plot

Tags: data-visualization, networks

In a [Hive Plot](http://www.hiveplot.net/) nodes are placed on lines and connections between groups are highlighted. This plot seems to lose the connections between nodes on the same line. It seems like an intentional loss of data to build a better plot, but is it possible to not lose this information in such a plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is intentional, more that it is unavoidable. And because of this information loss, hive plots are usually presented under the form of pannels of several plots, each one presenting the same network with different attributes for the axes/axis position.

[image: http://www.hiveplot.net/conference/ismb2011/netbiosig/hivepanel-human-dip-small.png]

See [this page](http://www.hiveplot.net/) for some examples and more details.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen many of these in the wild, but using a panel is a great way to accomplish this!